# Как узнать, какой пользователь запустил sudo?

Tags: python, linux, sudo

Мне необходимо записать данные в файл, который требует прав администратора. Причём мне нужно, чтобы такой скрипт работал без sudo, потому что мне нужно текущее имя пользователя, а при запуске с sudo оно заменяется на 'root', что мне не подходит:

```
import getpass
print(getpass.getuser())
# Output: 'root' при запуске скрипта с sudo
```

Так что мою проблему решит одно из двух: либо как поменять 'root' на текущее имя пользователя, либо как выполнить запись данных файл с правами администратора, реализуя это на Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

логичнее и проще узнать имя пользователя, выполнившего программу *sudo*.

например, в запущенном программой *sudo* процессе можно воспользоваться переменной окружения `SUDO_USER`, которая, согласно [`man sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo), устанавливается программой *sudo* в имя того пользователя, который её вызвал:

> SUDO_USER        Set to the login name of the user who invoked sudo.

---

в python можно получить значение переменной окружения, [например, так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4907053/4827341):

```
import os
print os.environ['SUDO_USER']
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Так заработало. Про 'SUDO_USER' не знал. Надо будет подучить линух...

Comment: знать (и даже помнить) не обязательно. достаточно выдвинуть гипотезу, проверить (`$ sudo env | grep $USER`) и найти подтверждение в документации (`$ man -P cat sudo | grep SUDO_USER`).

Comment: На практике не проверял, но, думается, переменную окружения нетрудно будет подделать, если вдруг кому-то очень приспичит, так что аккуратно

Comment: @andreymal, да, часто (но далеко не всегда) **тот пользователь**, который запускает *sudo*, может **намеренно** передать целевой программе и другие значения переменных окружения.